Валидация полей обьекта в JAVA
Eсть контроллер который принимает json-обеькт с полями: string text, long userId, long contentId.
При наличии полей id идет проверка на наличие пользователя и контента по их id, при отсутствии объектов по id выпадает ошибка 404.
Проблема в обработке Обьекта в котором не указаны userID и contentID. Когда объект попадает в контроллер id инициируются как "0". Должна быть ошибка 400.
Как выводить ошибку 400 с тем что объект не заполнен?

нуна поменять long на Long в определениях userId и contentId.
а ищо добавить @NotNull чтоб валидация случилась.
